# rails errors in dependencies.rb

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4.0
Heroku
Hi! I'm trying to push an app on Heroku but I'm having this following error. I couldn't find dependencies.rb in my app. I ran Heroku logs.

```
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453214+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.452641+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.452641+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.452641+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.452641+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.452799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.452799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.452799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453382+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453214+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453382+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.452799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453053+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453053+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453053+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453053+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453382+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453382+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.452799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453053+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453214+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453382+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453214+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453382+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453214+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453214+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453214+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453382+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453382+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453382+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453382+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453382+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-02-03T03:36:14.453382+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2014-02-03T03:36:16.045779+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-02-03T03:36:20.388355+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 35219 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2014-02-03T03:36:25.027178+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-02-03T03:36:25.027178+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-02-03T03:36:25.027178+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-02-03T03:36:25.027178+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028249+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/ckeditor/attachment_file.rb:2:in `<class:AttachmentFile>'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028249+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:330:in `require_or_load'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028249+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `has_attached_file' for Ckeditor::AttachmentFile(no database connection):Class (NoMethodError)
2014-02-03T03:36:25.027178+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:35219
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028249+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/ckeditor/attachment_file.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028249+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028249+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028249+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028249+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028586+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029139+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028586+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028586+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028249+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:207:in `require_dependency'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028424+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028424+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028424+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028424+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028249+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:289:in `depend_on'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029139+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029139+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029139+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029139+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029139+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029139+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029139+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028424+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028586+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028586+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028586+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028424+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028586+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029700+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028424+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028424+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028424+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028586+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028586+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029139+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028586+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.028424+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029139+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029700+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029700+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029700+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2014-02-03T03:36:25.029319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-02-03T03:36:26.332106+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-03T03:36:26.317672+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-02-03T03:36:52.031888+00:00 heroku[run.2229]: Awaiting client
2014-02-03T03:36:52.070422+00:00 heroku[run.2229]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-02-03T03:36:52.163802+00:00 heroku[run.2229]: State changed from starting to up
2014-02-03T03:36:56.331175+00:00 heroku[run.2229]: Process exited with status 0
2014-02-03T03:37:09.606778+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mighty-hamlet-9445.herokuapp.com request_id=7aedbbe3-fe00-43c1-bbfb-d2ca8a535cbf fwd="99.241.49.222" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

It doesn't recognize ckeditor function Attachment file.

Comment: paste the **full backtrace**, not just a single line.

Comment: and one single line is useless.

Comment: I think that my problem start by when Heroku is `Running: rake assets:precompile`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing `paperclip` as a dependency at your gemfile:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': 
undefined method `has_attached_file' for Ckeditor::AttachmentFile(no database connection):Class (NoMethodError)
```